# Visual Studio Team Services Azure deployment (Unable to perform the operation ("Delete File") for the specified directory)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, azure, continuous-integration

Heys guys,

I'm trying to deploy my NodeJS web app from Visual Studio Team Services to Azure using the build steps:

1. npm
2. Gulp
3. Azure Web App Deployment

Everything works fine when I stopped the app in Azure manually before deploying. But when I deploy while the app is running I get the following error on the last build step (3):

```
Unable to perform the operation ("Delete File") for the specified directory ("D:\home\site\wwwroot\logs\error.log"). This can occur if the server administrator has not authorized this operation for the user credentials you are using. Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_SITE_FOLDER.
```

I doubt the build process has insufficient rights, but think the log file to override is still in use by the running web app.

I did not include the logs folder in my repository.

Anyone experienced this issue and can give some hints (might be automatically stopping and starting the services or prevent the build process from touching the file generally because it is not really necessary)?

Comment: Could you try to create a `deploy.cmd` file in the root directory. Please refer to http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2015/06/03/running-gulp-during-azure-git-deploys.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately this does not fix my problem. I used cmd scripts in my old build process but since I restructured my project I wanted to use the new build steps offered by Azure. It throws the same exception using the deploy.cmd when the services are running.

Comment: @Ca11e, per my understanding, node.js app in Azure writes logs into D:/home/logfiles/application folder unless we made any change in iisnode.yml file or web.config. May I know if you have used Gulp: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/10/22/using-gulp-in-node-js-azure-webapps/ in your application? Could you please let us know what that \logs\error.log has?

Comment: @MingXu-MSFT The error.log file is in my application directory because I write logs to that file. It therefore is locked by the application. I have used gulp to prepare my deployment package, which works fine when the apps are stopped. I have now a Powershell script to stop the Web App before the "Azure Web App Deployment" step and a Powershell script to start them afterwards. Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/azure/dn495288.aspx

Comment: Cool, glad to see you have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For everybody stumbling across:

The solution was to stop the services before the Azure Web App Deployment with a Powershell script and to start them afterwards.

```
param(
  [string] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
  $Name,

  [string] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
  $Slot 
)

Start-AzureWebsite -Name $Name -Slot $Slot
```